# Any shortcut or plugin to generate constructor with parameter JSONObject as following code

Tags: android, android-studio, boilerplate

```
class Person {
    String name;
    String age;

    public Person(JSONObject obj) throws exception{
        this.name = obj.getString("name");
        this.age = obj.getString("age");
    }
}
```

Those are few attributes but I have a huge list of other attributes. I know shortcut about how to create constructer, getter, setter. But I don't know a shortcut to create the above code automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use google's gson library
[gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

Like this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Person person = gson.fromJson(jsonInString, Person.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is more way you have to create getters and setters.

1. Go to your class you want to add getter and setter
2. Then press key is `Alt + Insert` or Right Click and choose generate
3. then you will able to see a menu and click generate setters and getter or constructor on your desire
4. after that choose the variables with `Ctrl` or `Shift`

Hope I answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate using right click.

OR

Key shortcut = `Alt + Insert`